# Let M be an infinite set and A be countable prove that there is a 1-1 correspondence between $A\cup M$ and M

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let M be an infinite set and A be countable prove that there is a 1-1 correspondence between $A\cup M$ and M.

can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: **Hint:** You'll need the Axiom of Choice (or at least Dependent Choice) or something equivalent to that. With this, prove that $M$ has a (proper or improper) countably infinite subset.

Comment: I did not understand the axiom of choice so well, Could you recommend books for me or sources to understand it from, thank you :) @HenningMakholm

Comment: (Correction to the above: I _think_ I dimly remember something about Countable Choice actually being enough for this, but the details elude me).

Comment: x @Smart: If you try to prove _informally_ that $M$ must have a countably infinite subset, then what you come up with is likely to be the standard argument that needs the Axiom of Choice when you formalize it.

Comment: One of *many* duplicates around the site.